# Importing module works in terminal but no in IDLE

Tags: python, terminal, pygame, python-import

I just installed pygame on my Windows machine using Python3.7 and it works in terminal.
But when I tried to import it in the IDLE I get this error:-

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:\My projects\Python\PyGame\Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Answer (score 0):

go to python/scripts folder, open a command window to this path, type the following:

```
C:\python34\scripts> python -m pip install pygame --user
```

to test it, open python IDE and type

```
import pygame

print (pygame.ver)
```

Comment: I already installed pygame module but still it gives same error.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your error and also the screenshot of what code you are trying to execute ?